# how to set same height on responsive thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, responsive-design

I try to add this code to my page  and it doesn't work ? Can someone tell me why ?

http://www.booclin.ovh/tom/1/test.html

```js
var gallery = $('.photos').gallerify({ margin:10,
mode:{ maxHeight: screen.height * 0.5,
breakPoints:[
    
    
{ minWidth: 1170, columns: 4, },
{ minWidth: 970,  columns: 3, },
{ minWidth: 750,  columns: 2, },
{ maxWidth: 750,  columns: 1, }
    
    
]},lastRow:'adjust' });
```

```css
.photos { margin:auto; font-size:0px; }

.photo { position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  
<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x320">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x900">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/900x600">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x280">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x900">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/900x600">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x280">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x400">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/600x900">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/900x600">

<img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/900x600">

</div>




<!-- Scripts -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/xremix/xGallerify/master/dist/jquery.xgallerify.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0{ max-width: 500px; height:500px; float:left; width: 23%; margin:5px 5px 0px 5px; background-color:#1E1E1E; overflow:hidden;  }


@media (max-width: 1260px) { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 30%; } }

@media (max-width: 1024px) { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 47%; } }

@media (max-width: 500px)  { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 98%; } }
```

```html
<div class="right">


<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>


<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/03.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>


</div>
```

How can I set a ration in my jsfiddle. This is exactly what I need but I have a problem only with my height.

[Demo jsfiddle (NSFW)!](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/00mpcn8w/1/)

Comment: Dude, **NSFW** warning please!

Comment: Done, sorry for the mistake

Comment: any ideas about my question ?

Comment: You want the same height on different images size?

Comment: Its look fine, so what is your problem?

Comment: i can't see it working on my page and in jsfiddle i can only if I add script directly in html square not in external files, do you know what i forget ?

Comment: now it works on jsfiddle i work on my page but don't understand yet why it doesn't work, i work on a page, I share my link in 2min

Comment: I added my link if you want to take a look @ZeevKatz

Answer (score 0):

You can use image as **background-image** and change their background-size to **cover**.

```css
ul,li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
.fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0{
  max-width: 500px; 
  height:500px; 
  float:left;
  width: 23%; 
  margin:5px 5px 0px 5px; 
  background-color:#1E1E1E; 
  overflow:hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 img{
  visibility: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 1260px) { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 30%; } }

@media (max-width: 1024px) { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 47%; } }

@media (max-width: 500px)  { .fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0 { width: 98%; } }
```

```html
<ul class="right">
  
<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg')">
    <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>

<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>

<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/03.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/03.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>


<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>

<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/02.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>

<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/04.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>

<li class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook0" style="background-image: url('http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg')">
  <img src="http://www.starkasia.com/wp-content/uploads/book4/01.jpg" alt="Book 4"/>
</li>


</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: nice example, my goal is to have and keep different width

Comment: yep have it in tab ;)

Comment: thank you ;D I've updated my question at this time and I'm sure I'm really close